# how to deal with uncertain amount of sentences in different instances within a batch?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, reasoning

I encountered a coding problem. In my dataset, an instance includes several sentences (different amounts in different instances). They can not be concatenated to serve as a single one. How can I effectively process this kind of data with PyTorch? Or I have to process instance one by one?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. However, I can think of two less complex solutions.

1. Use a dummy sentence to pad the instances and mask the dummy sentences while learning representations for the instance.
2. You can group the instances based on the number of sentences to create mini-batches to avoid padding. However, if this is not a case, at least try to group instances which are similar in the number of sentences to minimize the amount of padding.

You can study existing implementations of learning document representations, for example, [Hierarchical Attention Networks for Document Classification paper](https://github.com/cedias/Hierarchical-Sentiment).